# using another class object for signal and slots inside qt

Tags: c++, qt

Consider the following scenario:

I have integrated QT in my c++ app. I wish to enter Data from a GUI rather than terminal. For this purpose, i created a function for QT. My dialog window consists of three text lines and a button, upon the click of which i want to call a particular method of some other class. I am having trouble with SINGAL and SLOTS.

Consider the following files:

```
main.cpp has 
a.h -> a.cpp

a.cpp has 
a.h
myslots.h
```

and the QT app method inside a.cpp as:

```
int A::inputData(){
...
A a
myslots ms;
QObject::connect(button, SIGNAL(clicked()), &ms, SLOT(clickButton(&a)));
....
}
```

myslots.h has:

```
a.h and inherited from A as:
class myslots : public QObject, public A {
Q_OBJECT
public slots:
    void clickButton(A &a);
signals:
    void buttonClicked();
};
```

myslots.cpp has:

```
myslots.h and the following method
void myslots::clickButton(A &a) {
        cout <<"I am called successfully"<<endl;
        a.perform_action(-2.3, 4.5, 4.4);
        emit this->buttonClicked();
}
```

I get the following error:

```
QObject::connect: No such slot myslots::clickButton(&a)
```

Actually i want to pass three double values from three textlines say: 1.3, 2.4, 4.5 to a function by clicking the button, where the function to be called is in another class that is inherited by myslots.h and accepts three parameters.

Currently am just testing whether i am able to call the function properly or not but am not.

Thanks

Comment: Have you got the `Q_OBJECT` macro in your classes?

Comment: Yes, i do have in myslots.h

Comment: You cannot pass arguments inside the `connect` statement. You can only do that when you emit signals: `emit mySignal(&a);`.

Comment: You want to pass the local variable `a` as an argument to the slot? This cannot work, as the local variable no longer exists when the slot is called. What you could do is connecting the `clicked` signal to a slot in class `A`, and from this slot emit a new signal, including `this` as the argument.

Answer (score 2):

Some issues:

1 - When tou derive from QObject, always put the Q_OBJECT macro in the private section of your class, do something like

```
class MyClass: public QObject {
    Q_OBJECT
public:
   ...
```

this Q_OBJECT macro is important for classes that have signals and slots.

2 - In the connect statement you have to tell Qt the type of the parameters, not the names you use, that is, if you slot function is

```
void myslots::clickButton(A &a);
```

The you connect to it with

```
connect(emiterObject, SIGNAL(someSignal(A)), targetObject, SLOT(clickButton(A)));
```

Comment: Note: passing a reference to a local variable in a signal is a Bad Thing.

Answer (score 2):

This will not work. In **SIGNAL** or **SLOT** must be a type, not an object or its reference. I mean this

```
QObject::connect(button, SIGNAL(clicked()), &ms, SLOT(clickButton(&a)));
```

must be

```
QObject::connect(button, SIGNAL(clicked()), &ms, SLOT(clickButton(A)));
```

But then you must catch another error - where is A in your **SIGNAL**? Why do you use A in the signal at all?

Answer (score 1):

Since Qt 5.x you are able to use a lambda expression as slot.

So your connect statement should look like:

```
QObject::connect(button, &QPushButton::clicked, [a, ms](){ms.clickButton(&a);});
```

But, using `a` and `ms` as local variables is not realy a good thing, as stated by Karsten Koop.

Answer (score 0):

The error is in your :

```
QObject::connect(button, SIGNAL(clicked()), &ms, SLOT(clickButton(&a)));
```

it has to be:

```
QObject::connect(button, SIGNAL(clicked(A)), &ms, SLOT(clickButton(A)));
```

the type that you send in the SIGNAL must be in SLOT that receives that type.